# How to feed to "The Wall" moo tools plugin JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mootools

I fount this great plugin called ["The Wall"](http://wall.plasm.it/) but sadly neither the docs nor the [examples](http://wall.plasm.it/examples/) show how to feed to it JSON objects.

Say we have JSON array like:

```
[
 {
   href : "/my/photo/image1.jpg",
   title : "Me and Sara"
 },
 {
   href : "/my/photo/image2.jpg",
   title : "Me and Sara on a trip"
 },
 {
   href : "/my/photo/image3.jpg",
   title : "Me and Sara on a vacation"
 }
]
```

(It can and should be bigger) but I hope you get the point. How do I make "The Wall" create a wall of images out of such JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thing like:

```
var images = [
{
  href : "/my/photo/image1.jpg",
  title : "Me and Sara"
},
{
  href : "/my/photo/image2.jpg",
  title : "Me and Sara on a trip"
},
{
  href : "/my/photo/image3.jpg",
  title : "Me and Sara on a vacation"
 }
];
var counterFluid = 1;
var maxLength = images.length;
var wallFluid = new Wall("wall", {
                                "draggable":true,
                                "inertia":true,
                                "width":150,
                                "height":150,
                                "rangex":[-100,100],
                                "rangey":[-100,100],
                                callOnUpdate: function(items){
                                    items.each(function(e, i){
                                        var a = new Element("img[src=" + images[(counterFluid -1)].href + "]");
                                            a.inject(e.node).fade("hide").fade("in");
                                        counterFluid++;
                                        // Reset counter
                                        if( counterFluid > maxLength ) counterFluid = 1;
                                    })
                                }
                            });
// Init Fluid Wall
wallFluid.initWall();
```

Comment: It would be cool if you could provide a JsFiddle example. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.webtogs.co.uk/thewall/ - look at source, i did that for my old employers, fed by json with real data of all their products with video reviews.